# Pulling Data Between Tables Using =IF Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

I am trying to create a Fantasy Football Cheat sheet since my league drafts offline. The excel file has two sheets, one with all of the available players to draft sorted in a table, the other with my team as I draft them sorted into a table. I am trying to make it so I can mark a player with a designated letter and that will trigger the players information to be pulled into my team table.

What I have figured out is that I am able to pull the information into the other table every time I place an `L` (for Logan) in the drafted column using this formula:

```
=IF(Table2[[#All],[Drafted]]="L",Table2[Player Name], "Empty")
```

The issue I am having is the `IF` function pulls the player data, but it pulls it into the same cell in sheet 2 that the player is located in on sheet 1. I need to get it so the table looks for the next `L` and pulls in the player data into the next empty spot on the team table. Refer to the image below:

[image: https://madshot.net/2af3822b36b1.png]

I appreciate any suggestions to help me get past this road block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula entered at the first cell for column `Player`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[Player Name],
   AGGREGATE(15,6, Table2[ADP]/(Table2[Drafted]="L"),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

You can use `VLookup` for the other columns once the players' names were imported. Alternatively you can use the same formula just by substituting `Table2[Player Name]` with the appropriate column, i.e. `Table2[Position]`.

p.s. I used `Table2[ADP]` to benefit from the existence of the row numbers in the table, instead of the otherwise more complex `ROW(Table1[Drafted])-ROW(Table1[#Headers])`.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!